# Call Google Cloud Functions from App Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-functions

i am quite new to the GCP world and i am asking here just to have some other informations about my issue.

I would like to create an HTTP Google Cloud Function that performs some operations over a certain project.

At the same way, i need to invoke this function from an external service (let's say from a Gsheet for which the SA that own the function could edit it).

I saw that there is GoogleAppScripts, and in particular the URLFetchApp service.
My idea is to call that function from that service.

In order to have authentication i saw that the library OAuth2 is needed, in this case, is it necessary to create a ClientID and a ClientSecret for the account that manage the function? If this is the case, how the AppScript could create the related service?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: generateIdToken didn't work for me when I started out (permission error), but it miraculously started working on the SECOND day without any change on my part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can query the identity token via google apps script and then use it to call the gcloud function.

The first thing we have to do is to have a cloud function and make sure you have permissions to invoke it (try executing it using another method).

After that, go to your Apps Script project manifest and [set at least 2 specific scopes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes):

```json
{
  ...
  "oauthScopes": [
    "openid",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"
  ],
 ...
}
```

`openid` allows us to get an identity token to call the function with and `.../script.external_request` allows us to use a fetch.

Then you can add the code:

```js
const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
  'https://gcloud-function-url',
  {
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${ScriptApp.getIdentityToken()}`
    }
  }
)

// use response
```

As [documented in the reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getidentitytoken), `ScriptApp.getIdentityToken()` returns the the OpenID token that we need.

### References

- [Authenticating Developers, Functions, and End-users
  (Google Cloud guides)](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating)
- [UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params) (Google Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)
- [ScriptApp.getIdentityToken() (Google Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getidentitytoken)

Comment: thank you for the reply. In case this sheet is managed by another user that do not have access to the GCP Project is still able to call the required function?

Comment: It depends on your setup. It uses the auth token of the effective user ([see reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getEffectiveUser())). If it's an installed trigger, it will have the permissions of who created that trigger. In most other scenarios, the other user. The other way is to allow anonymous calls to the function. In that case no `Authorization` header would be required.

Comment: @traveller is it really working? I though that the getOAuthToken replied an access token and to access to the function you need an identity token!

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere You are actually right. This also means that you need to add your identity token manually, and thus it doesn't effect who calls the function.

Comment: @Martí, if you know how to achieve this properly and securely, it could be very valuable. There is a "black hole" in the Google Cloud documentation between the possible connexion between Google Cloud and Workspace (app script, app sheet) world!!

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere not at all, probably i am doing something wrong. I am able to execute the cloud functions with authentication inside cloud shell (e.g. by using curl), but by pasting url on chrome let's say i am not authorized even if i added the CloudFunctions Invoker permission to that user. Morevoer when i move outside like a GoogleAppScript i got "401 Unauthorized Your client does not have permission to the requested URL". Anyway the suggestion of where very helpful.

Comment: Sorry, black hole!! There no or very few or outdated documentation on that. I keep an eyes on this question in case of someone know how to achieve that!

Comment: I have some update on this, yesterday the ScriptApp.getIdentityToken() return null. After reading the documentation i added the required scope to the manifest and i was able to get all the user information. However it still says error 401 Unauthorized. I have the function on a certain GCP Project (and as i said i am able to call it with curl) , while the script is in the Default one. Could be this the problem? I

Comment: Hey! I've made it work! I've updated the answer :)

Comment: Hi @Martí, thank you for your reply. This is exaclty what i was done. However i still get 401 error. By "try executing it using another method"  what do you mean? I am able to call functions only via curl, by calling directly the URL i got 403 Forbinnen. Morevover, the App Scripts it is not linked to the same project where the function reside. In your opinion there is something wrong? I should change the way how can i call function or i need to link script with project?

Comment: @traveller Then it's probably the code on the cloud function. Try with the default hello world. Also this makes a `GET` request, so if you are expecting a `POST` you will need to change it.

Comment: I Was trying already with this code actually: (https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/http)  the only difference is that i do not want to use the --allow-unauthenticated. I am aware of the new policy of Google for functions, so in order to call via url i should add to allUsers the cloud invoker permission. The only thing i am not sure are: 1: if i need to connect script to gcp project, 2: if i need to create an api key and eventually attach it to the URL and 3: if to work i need to deploy scripts as Api Executable.

Comment: @traveller No, you don't need any of that. The only thing you need is to add you user to the list of people with invoke permission. After that execute the function that contains this code and it should work. ([see authentication reference](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#developers))

Comment: I couldn't get this answer to work. Instead I found that using `ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()` for the `Bearer` did the trick. This Github repo helped: https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2/tree/master/samples/NoLibrary

Answer (score 2):

This works as stated in @Martí 's answer, but I spent a very frustrating day having it not work because I missed a tiny but crucial step: **You need to redeploy the Cloud Function after making the Apps Script, otherwise it won't have the Client ID validated!** The Apps Script is assigned this ID when you associate it with the same GCP Project, so redeploy the Function after that.